# How do I make a matter body isStatic false after pressing a key in matter.js?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I was working on a project where I found it difficult to figure out how to make a Matter Body in matter.js `isStatic` false when a key is pressed.

```js
if (keyIsPressed(UP_ARROW)) {
  this.body.isStatic(false)
}
```

Can you tell what is the correct syntax to make a Matter body `isStatic` false when a key is pressed?

Comment: [Relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/187). Try [`Matter.Body.setStatic(body, isStatic)`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#method_setStatic).

Answer (score 2):

Static bodies in MatterJS have infinite mass. Long story short, if you want to change a body from `isStatic=true` to `isStatic=false`, you have to also set the mass.

```
Matter.Body.setMass(myBody, 0.001 * (myBody.width * myBody.height))
Matter.Body.setStatic(myBody, false)
```

0.001 is the [default body density](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/014ef77d1e30b44cb65098c0efc9c9d623a40496/src/body/Body.js#L63). We multiply that by the area to get the mass.

reference: [MatterJS GitHub Question](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/187)

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
function keyPressed(){
    if (keyCode === 38){
     isStatic : false}
}
```

but before pls check u have matter.js and p5.js